# ASP.NET MVC initial controller set up using the context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, dbcontext

This error occurs when using the default set up below

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'MangaShop.Data.MangashopContext' while attempting to activate 'MangaShop.Controllers.MangasController'

Code:

```
public MangasController(MangashopContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}
```

And when I use this I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure' to the 'UseSqlServer' call.

```
public MangasController()
{
    _context = new MangashopContext();
    _context.Database.EnsureCreated();
}
```

But then it will work as normal if I run it again. What is happening here and how can I make this run properly?

I also believe this to be related to the problem but I get the error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Context was null.

When trying to run this line of code in an attempt to seed data into the database.

```
public class Seed
{
    public static void SeedData(IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)
    {
        using var serviceScope = applicationBuilder.ApplicationServices.CreateScope();
        var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MangakashopContext>();

        context.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This error occurs when using the default set up below
>
> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'MangaShop.Data.MangashopContext' while attempting to activate 'MangaShop.Controllers.MangasController'

To inject your classes into other classes you have to register them in dependency injection container. In case of ASP.NET Core MVC app it can be done in Program.cs file. Follow instructions from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/uk-ua/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#dbcontext-in-dependency-injection-for-aspnet-core) but use `builder.Services` from `Main` method instead of `services` from `ConfigureServices` method

In result you should have code like this

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    // You should not store connection strings in plain sight but for now it'll do
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<MangashopContext>(
        opt => opt.UseSqlServer("your connection string here")
    );
    ...
}
```

P.S. Better way to seed data is using override of `OnModelCreating` method in your data context class. You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding)

Comment: I needed to also add the constructor to my Context class.

public MangashopContext(DbContextOptions<MangashopContext> options)
: base(options)
{
}

But this worked well. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to also add the constructor to my Context class.

```
public MangashopContext(DbContextOptions<MangashopContext> options) : base(options) { }
```

But the solution from Ihor Lupyna, is what was needed. Thank you very much.

Comment: Given that, this would probably make more sense as a comment on their post, not a new answer.